# hapi-swagger response example support

Tags: hapi-swagger

I tried adding response example to hapi controller routes, but it does not render, neither is part of the swagger.json file hapi-swagger plugin generates.

Does hapi-swagger supports respose examples?
https://swagger.io/docs/specification/adding-examples

```
 responses: {
                200: {
                    description: 'Successful',
                    schema: Joi.object({
                        status: Joi.string(),
                        output: Joi.string()
                    }),
                    "examples": {
                      "MyFirstExample": {
                        "value": {
                          "status": 'Running',
                           "output": "Work in Progress"
                    }
                  }
                }
                },
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.